# jQuery Button fade loop until another button is pressed

Tags: jquery

This is what I want to accomplish.
I have two buttons,  when I press the first one it fades out to 50% and when the fade out is complete it fades back  up to 100% and then it loops the animation for ever until another button is pressed, and den the next button does exactly the same. So every time a button is clicked it just softly blink… 
Is this posible?

I’ve been toying whit this but just don’t get it to work.

```
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
<style type="text/css">
#blnk a { cursor: pointer; }
</style>

<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
$("#blnk a img").children().click(function(){
          $(this).animate({"backgroundColor":""},500);},
    function(){
          $(this).animate({"backgroundColor":""},500);});
//-->
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="blnk"><a src="#"><img src="http://www.auviproducciones.com/more/imagenes/imagen5.jpg"></a></div>
    <div id="blnk"><a src="#"><img src="http://www.auviproducciones.com/more/imagenes/imagen6.jpg"></a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a jsFiddle that solves your problem. I'm sure you can adapt it to your code : http://jsfiddle.net/SFYGX/2/

Let me explain what I've done there: At click, I'm reseting all opacities to 1, and stopping all the animations, and then, I'm starting a recursive loop to animate the clicked item.

(Before trying it, make sure you don't use duplicate id's like you are doing now (id="blnk"))

Comment: Genius... it works great, more than great... Perfect!
Where can I go on line and learn to do this you guys do so well?

Answer (score 0):

on the animate function there is a callback you could use. If you put your animation in a function you could use the callback to call the function again. Within the function you could include a flag that is set when something happens and stops the loop or calls another function.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

javascript:

```
$(function() {
    var currentId;
    var animate = function(obj) {
            if (currentId == $(obj).attr('id')) $(obj).fadeTo('slow', 0.5, function() {
                $(obj).fadeTo('slow', 1);
                animate(obj);
            });
        }
    $(".blnk a img").click(function() {
        currentId = $(this).attr('id');
        animate(this);
    });
});
```

​html:

```
<div class="blnk"><a src="#"><img id="img1" src="http://www.auviproducciones.com/more/imagenes/imagen5.jpg"></a></div>
<div class="blnk"><a src="#"><img id="img2" src="http://www.auviproducciones.com/more/imagenes/imagen6.jpg"></a></div>
```

css:

```
.blnk a { cursor: pointer; } ​
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/usernamedemanded/MBsnN/11/)